# Which of these structures are for exact Nearest Neighbor and which ones for approximate version?

Tags: data-structures, nearest-neighbor, dimension, kdtree, approximate-nn-searching

LSH is a popular algorithm for ANN.

k-d Tree is maybe the most popular solution for exactly solving NN.

However, reading [this survey](http://search.proquest.com/openview/c727ee6e4354dea443de93c40071108e/1?pq-origsite=gscholar) I found these structures and I don't understand which ones are for solving NN or ANN:

- quad/oct-tree
- ball-tree
- R-Tree
- M-Tree

I didn't found any survey dedicated to ANN, so I think that all of these are for NN and for metric spaces (they cannot be used for non-metric spaces).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to contain a single question? I can only post one answer. If you think then that need to ask more, post a new q. ;)

Comment: Now there is no super obvious question. I guess you mean which of the 4 structures you have are used for Nearest Neigbor searching?

Comment: No, my question is: which of these stucrure are used for EXACT NN and which for APPPROXIMATE NN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me confirm that [quadtree](http://www.cse.ust.hk/faculty/arya/pub/stoc11.pdf), [Ball tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree#Nearest-neighbor_search), [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and [M-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-tree) can be used for Nearest Neighbor Search (NNS).

Now if a structure can support NNS, then it *can* support approximate Nearest Neighbor search.

Take for example the kd-tree, which you might know better; it collects point-candidates that may be the answer to a query. If you check *all* the possible candidates, then you can answer the exact Nearest Neighbor query. If you check *some* of the candidates, then you can answer the approximate Nearest Neighbor query.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I suggested an edit but it was rolled back to a previous version. Am I right in suggesting that some candidates will lead to an approx NN result? It seems right to me

Comment: @fzk yes, thank you very much and for the upvote! =)

Comment: is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html an absolute NN?